# How to pass URL params in angular $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm converting a server side CRUD app to Angular.js and have a small problem.

I'm getting my data with `$http` and display all the data via `ng-repeat`. I want to make users able to click and a specific item and redirect them to the resource.

So how can I pass a URL param to the `$http` get call dynamically?

Here's how I built the link to the resource (car.id = 3)

```
<a ng-href="/#/cars/{{car.id}}">Edit</a>
```

The link should go to http://local.dev/#/cars/3

So how do I bind the dynamic url in my controller?

Here's a stripped down version of my controller

```
App.controller('CarIndexCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function ($scope, $http, $location) {

   $scope.car = {};

   $http({
     method: 'GET',
     url:  $location.$$url,
   })
   .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
     $scope.car = data;
   })
   .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
     // error
   });

}]);
```

So I'm interested to bind the URL the angular way. The above solution works, but feels very much like a hack. I'm not that familiar with Angular, so I like to stick to the defaults for now. I might consider restangular or ng-resource at a later time though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the above solution works, but feels very much like a hack.

I don't think its hack or something messy.

I would generate URL list in controller (from my view its better for code maintenance) without appending in HTML. Something like:

```
 $scope.urlList = [];

    $http({
     method: 'GET',
     url:  $location.$url,
   })
   .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
     $scope.car = data;
     $scope.urlList.push("/#/cars/" + data.id);
   })
   .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
     // error
   });
```

After in HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="url in urlList" repeat-done="layoutDone()" ng-cloak>
    <a ng-href="{{url}}">Edit</a>
</li>
```

BTW, I suggest you to use some loader because URL links we generate from promise (aka async) therefore with delay.

Demo <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vjF2D/11/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

In your app.js do something like this

```
 var app = angular.module('YourAPP');
        app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/cars/:CarID', {
                    templateUrl: 'app/views/cars.html',
                    controller: 'CarIndexCtrl'
                });
    });
```

And in your controller

```
    App.controller('CarIndexCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams) {

       $scope.car = {};
        $scope.carid = $routeParams.CarID;
       $http({
         method: 'GET',
         url:  $location.$$url,
       })
       .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
         $scope.car = data;
       })
       .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
         // error
       });

}]);
```

And use the carid in wherever in your controller. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you I will try your suggestion! So the url:  $location.$$url, method is something that is used normally. I somehow thought there was  a alternative method for binding the url.